# Compiling pascal program in Visual Studio Code for Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, pascal

Recently, I switched my OS to Ubuntu. I just started with collage and I have to learn pascal for my finals. But a problem occurred.

I installed Visual Studio Code and Pascal extension for it, but I am unable to run even a simple Hello World code. I wrote code, it saved automatically as .pas, but when I enter debug & run option in VSC it displays a message that says 'Open a file which can be debugged or run.', followed by 'debug' and 'run' buttons that I am unable to click and another message that says 'To further configure Debug and Run create a launch.json file.'

I am not even sure am I supposed to post questions such as this one on stackoverflow, but I sincerelly hope that someone could give me a hint on what to do. Solve this within Visual Studio Code or switch to another IDE (and which one would you recommend for Linux user) and pretend that nothing happened?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: While the Pascal extension supports the language configuration (syntax highlighting, formatting,navigation, etc.) it does not appear to support debugging the language.  And I don't see any vscode extension that looks like it would.  I did see an online Pascal debugger...

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't an answer to "how to debug with pascal with vscode" but, perhaps you would find it easier to just use FPC / Lazarus (IDE) to do your work. While it doesn't have a dark theme, contrary to popular belief, that's not necessary to program.
The IDE is feature packed and allows for full code completion, debugging, etc... (everything you really need to do the work for school).
Additionally, you can use this open source tool to install everything you need for your platform in just a few button clicks (also allows for installing common library packages)
https://github.com/LongDirtyAnimAlf/fpcupdeluxe/releases

- download release for your OS
- under "FPC Version" & "Lazarus Version" select trunkgit (or stable for an older version)
- click the "Install/Update FPC + Lazarus" button

Answer (score 0):

Have you Installed **Pascal** extension which is available for code to smoothly run pascal code.

If you haven't then try installing this extension using,

> Launch VS Code Quick Open (**Ctrl+P**), paste the following command, and press enter.
>
> ext install alefragnani.pascal

You can always check,

**https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alefragnani.pascal**

to install and configure pascal in vscode.

Comment: "I installed Visual Studio Code and Pascal extension" in the question...

Answer (score 0):

I will direct you to the [debugging page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging) from the Visual Studio Code documentation that details how to use the debugger and configure a `launch.json` file. VSCode is a generic IDE so you need to give it some information about your project before it knows how to run the debugger. This is what `launch.json` is for.

If I could make a suggestion. When you're learning how to program, it's best to start with the basics. Write a small program in a text editor (VSCode is fine, or Vim, or Nano, or Notepad, or whatever). Save the file. Compile and run the program on the command line.

Once you put an IDE in the mix, you have to learn how to use that as well. If you're stuck on both parts, it can be hard to make progress. That said, it's good to learn how to use the IDE, and you should spend some time reading the documentation and working through some of the examples. It takes some time, but it will pay you back a thousand times when you can work more quickly.